# Missing value replacement reference from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, samsung-mobile, fillna

how do i replace missing values from one dataframe referencing from another dataframe?

i have a dataframe (df_missing). df_missing has several missing values "S_months" and "incident".

[ship data with missing info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31xnn.png)

Seperately, i have prepared average data of S_months and "incident". I name it as df. I group the df with "Types" and "O_periods"

[Ship data with average Types and O_periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msQLR.png)

I am require to replace df_missing value of "S_months" and "incident" with df matching "Types" and "O_periods". For example, df_missing row6 has a missing value, i am suppose to replace it with data from df. For this instance of df_missing row 6 "Types" = 1 and "O_periods" = 1, the replacement will be S_months = 911.3 and "incident" = 3.0

I am able to identify the missing rows using the code below;

```
rownum=[]
DF_mode.isnull()
misrow=DF_mode.isnull().any(axis=1)
rownum=DF_mode.loc[misrow[misrow==True].index]
```

I am not sure how to write the code for replacement. should i use fillna()? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using the `transform` method.

```
df_missing[['S_months', 'Incidents']] = df_missing.groupby(['Types', 'O_periods']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))[['S_months', 'Incidents']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works amazingly. I learned near function today. Lambda and  transform.

Comment: Glad I could help!